# Chrome input="date" breaks tabindex

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, date

I have a form which contains an html5 date input element. Each input on the form is carefully ordered in the tabindex sequence. But the date element breaks the sequence in Chrome, sending the focus back to the first element. The same element works if I revert it back to a simple text input. Any ideas how to get around this? Any non-JS solutions get special mention.

Comment: You had better file a bug on <https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry> though I have no idea of workarounds.

Comment: Did you solve it? can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Javascript` to add the `tabIndex` to the input of type date once the page rendered, it should let you go through the expected tab index behaviour.

For example (inputs of type dates were given class 'dateInput' and index of some-number):

```
$(".dateInput").attr("tabIndex", some-number);
```

In my case, I was not able to tab through the document until the tabIndex was removed form the input of type date.